# How to add +1 to each element of array till a maximum value(which is known beforehand)?

Tags: java

I have an array for tables:

```
 int[] tables = new int[9]
```

I want to make it so each int in this array is the number of persons a table can have. int[9] so 10 tables in total.

If i have a maximum of 98 players i want the array to contain:

```
tables[0] = 10
tables[1] = 10
tables[2] = 10
tables[3] = 10
tables[4] = 10
tables[5] = 10
tables[6] = 10
tables[7] = 10
tables[8] = 9
tables[9] = 9
```

the sum of all ^ this is 98 now.

The array values are all 0 at the beginning, they have to add up till it reaches a sum of 98, the 98 can also be different, sometimes its 97, 96 etc.
thanks.

Comment: Right now your question is unclear. `How can i make the array add +1 to each element till the max (98 for now)` if the sum is already 98 why are you trying to add +1 to each element? To break your own rule? Can you explain it better please?

Comment: You could make a loop `for (int i=0; i<98; i++) { tables[figureOutTheIndexLeftAsExerciseTipRemainderOfDivision]++ }`. For higher numbers, it would be more efficient to just calculate the share for each element (Hint: division) , and set each element accordingly just once.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The array values are all 0 at the beginning, they have to add up till it reaches a sum of 98, is that better?

Comment: Your problem description is ambiguous.

Comment: @PM77-1 i tried to make it better!

Comment: Now it is. Thanks.

Comment: `new int[9]` only allocates 9 buckets, numbered 0 to 8. `tables[9]` doesn't exist.

Comment: Help us understand what you're trying to do with these arrays. Are you making teams of players and want to evenly distribute players?

Comment: You assign the number of players on the fly or is it predefined (the size of the array)? I mean, the array size is an user input?

Comment: @RichardBarker yes exactly! there are these tables, the amount of which is known beforehand, in this example there are 9. If there are 98 players they should evenly distribute, the difference between the number of players of each tables shouldnt be more than 1 or 2.

Comment: @JorgeCampos the number of players is predefined, its different, but for an array it stays the same.

Comment: @user1806846 see my answer

Comment: You are unclear. Suppose you are hiring me to do the work instead of calling the program. What is my job? What sequence of what tasks do you give me, and what sequence of what things do I give you back, in terms of it? PS Please respond to comments re clarifications by editing your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple loop of assigning number of players to tables, by how many are left. Since you want higher counts on the first set of tables, you always round *up*.

Example: 3 tables, 8 players
1st table gets `8 / 3 = 3` (rounded up)
That leaves 2 tables, 5 players
2nd table gets `5 / 2 = 3` (rounded up)
That leaves 1 table, 2 players
3rd table gets `2 / 1 = 2`
Result: **`[3, 3, 2]`**

Code:

```
private static int[] buildTables(int noOfTables, int noOfPlayers) {
    int[] tables = new int[noOfTables];
    for (int i = 0, playersLeft = noOfPlayers; i < noOfTables; playersLeft -= tables[i++]) {
        int tablesLeft = noOfTables - i;
        tables[i] = (playersLeft + tablesLeft - 1) / tablesLeft; // round up
    }
    return tables;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(3, 8)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(9, 5)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(9, 98)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(10, 98)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(10, 96)));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buildTables(10, 88)));
```

*Output*

```
[3, 3, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9]
[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 9]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8]
```

If you didn't do the `+ tablesLeft - 1` to cause round-up, the result would be:

```
[2, 3, 3]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]
[9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
[9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
[8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Comment: `2 / 1 = 2` last I checked; but, brilliant answer nonetheless!

Comment: @Obicere Sorry, typo. Had the right number on the next line. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are clearly learning I will not provide code. This is basic logic, so I will propose one of many ways to solve it.

If you know the size of the array, create a variable to hold the total of points to be distributed (in your case 98)

Then create a loop that iterate until the total of points reachs 0

Create an inner loop to iterate on the arrays of players

Inside this loop you check again if you still have points and if so you increase the points of the current position in the array and decreases the total of points by 1

There are many ways to do it. This is only one, may not be the best one but it will work.

Comment: When you put it like that, you might as well just write the code! ;p

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, we calculate the minimum number of players that should be at each table, and then the number of tables that need to take an extra player. Then, the loop makes the appropriate assignment.

```
    int total_tables = 10;
    int total_players = 98;
    int min_players_per_table = total_players / total_tables;
    int tables_with_extra_player = total_players % total_tables;
    int[] tables = new int[total_tables];
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tables_with_extra_player) {
        tables[i++] = min_players_per_table + 1;
    }
    while (i < total_tables) {
        tables[i++] = min_players_per_table;
    }
```

Comment: I did a benchmark comparing your and @Andreas solutions plus some others. Yours (`distribute2`) seems to be the fastest, I also included a haskell version for those interested.

https://gist.github.com/Centril/5a0dbf6a46e73e3913388214c0e2fa52

Comment: @Centril: Hmmm. Two while loops may perform better, then.

Comment: Updated benchmarks accordingly.. And added a c++ version... It seems to perform slightly better, around 2% which is surely within the margin of error and is probably Java specific. On some platforms, you could use `SIMD` instructions to gain even better performance. Unfortunately, since we are not dealing with `char`s it won't be optimized to `memset`...

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on @jxh, all credit goes to him/her.
The only difference is using `Array.fill` and some cosmetic changes:

```
int[] distribute4( int total, int nBuckets ) {
    int bucketsWithExtra = total % nBuckets;
    int minimumForAll = total / nBuckets;
    int[] buckets = new int[nBuckets];
    Arrays.fill( buckets, 0, bucketsWithExtra, minimumForAll + 1 );
    Arrays.fill( buckets, bucketsWithExtra, nBuckets, minimumForAll );
    return buckets;
}
```

This solution is the fastest for large bucket sizes which can be seen in this benchmark: https://gist.github.com/Centril/5a0dbf6a46e73e3913388214c0e2fa52

If you are interested, here is also a `haskell` version of the code above:

```hs
import Data.List (genericReplicate)
distribute4 :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]
distribute4 sum nBuckets =
    let bucketsWithExtra = sum `rem` nBuckets
        minimumForAll = sum `div` nBuckets
        start = genericReplicate bucketsWithExtra (minimumForAll + 1)
        end = genericReplicate (nBuckets - bucketsWithExtra) minimumForAll
    in start ++ end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Fits the number of players into different bins. */
public static final void thinkIUnderstandYourQuestion(final int[] pArray, int pPlayers) { 
     /* Clear the Array that's already been allocated. */
     Arrays.fill(pArray, 0);
     /* Declare the iteration variable. */
     int i = 0;
     /* Iterate the array whilst there are players to assign. */
     do { 
          /* Increment the value at a wrapped index. They'll start off as none, and we'll just keep adding one to them whilst we reduce the number of players. */
          pArray[i++ % pArray.length]++;
     }
     /* Whilst there are players to assign. */
     while(pPlayers-- != 0) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to do this differently then. this isnt valid code - its pseudocode to show logic.

first get the number of players per team:

```
numOfPlayers = 98;
numOfTeams = 9;
Teams = new Array[numOfTeams]();
leftOverPlayers = (numOfPlayers % numOfTeams); // this gets you the remainder; this case, 8
TotalPlayersPerTeam = (numOfPlayers - leftOverPlayers) / numOfTeams // gets you the minimum number of players per team, this case this will be 10
```

by this point, you have enough to make your team array. Init every value in the array to TotalPlayersPerTeam, then loop through the array adding one to the current value in the array and subtracting one from the left over until leftOverPlayers = 0. this will actually produce an array with 11 players for the first 8 teams, and 10 for the last.

```
i = -1
do
     i++
     team[i] = TotalPayersPerTeam
     if leftOverPlayers > 0 
         team[i]++
         leftOverPlayers--
while (i < numOfTeams)
```

If you used 10 for numOfTeams, you'd get the output that is listed in your question.

Comment: I actually used one loop to pull it off; if you used two, you wouldnt need the if statememt.

Answer (score 0):

suppose size of array is n.You want to sum upto k.

```
count = 0
for(int i = 0;i<k;i++)
{
    a[count] +=1;
    count +=1
    if((count-1) % n ==0)
       count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] tables=new int[9];// 9 considered to be number of teams
int maxNumber=98;//number of players
int j=0;//counter
while(maxNumber>0){//loop until all players have teams
    if(j>tables.length-1){
        j=0;
    }
    tables[j]=tables[j]+1;//add player in team
    maxNumber=maxNumber-1;//decrease number of players
    j=j+1;
}

//display data
for(int i=0;i<tables.length;i++){
  System.out.println(tables[i]);
}
```

Comment: Doing it this way will be orders of magnitude slower than @jxh and Andreas solutions. The other solutions except for the 2 I've enumerated also suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can state explicitly what each table[i] is.

Assume n tables (n > 0) and int p players (p >= 0).

Every table[i] gets at least p / n players. If i <  p % n then add 1 else 0.

```
int p = 16; // number of players (p >=0)
int t = 10; // number of tables (t > 0)
int[] tables = new int[t];
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    tables[i] = p / t + (i < p % t ? 1 : 0);
}
```